# mocking api call with jest spyOn not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs

I have the following context provider component (I am using the context api)

Example code:

```
export class AppProvider extends Component {
    contructor (props) {
        super(props);
    }

    fetchOrder () {
        // http request
        return Promise.all(promises).then(result => console.log(result));
    }

    updateOrder (id) {
        // ...
        this.fetchOrder(id).then(result => this.setState(result));
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <emailContext.Provider
                value={{
                    state: this.state,
                    updateOrder: this.updateOrder
                }}
            >
                {this.props.children}
            </emailContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

I am writing a test for `updateOrder` but I need to mock the `fetchOrder` http request being called by `updateOrder`.

I thouht I could just mock it like so:
`jest.spyOn(AppProvider, 'fetchOrder').mockResolvedValue('fake value');` but this gives: 
`Cannot spy the fetchOrder property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`

I get the same if I put `updateOrder` instead of `fetchOrder`.

Why is this happening? And if this is not the way to do this, how will I intercept that request in my test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `fetchOrder` is not a property on `AppProvider`, but its a property ( a method property) on its instances. You have to mock the method on the instance, and while this is will work it is better to mock the endpoint itself using request interceptors. This will make you test the instance from the outside world without having to be completely coupled with its implementation.

Comment: How do you mock interceptors? the api call is made from anothere file being called in `fetchOrder`, And that uses a plain js `fetch` call. We're not using axios.